Bespoke Modelica.Fluid.DynamicPipe model
I am need to modify the Fluid.DynamicPipe model for a specific application (it cannot be done with the flow model, but needs to be the DynamicPipe).
While this was easy enough with MSL3.x where I could just make a copy in my local MSL and modify it there. With this, the extends worked nicely.  Yet with MSL4.x, one cannot modify the library.
This leaves me having to make a local copy in my own model structure.  It is here that issues arrive.  The my modified code is below.  With the changes I made, I would expect the compiler to look at the original MSL4.x models as needed, but it doesn’t seem to want to - if returns the message below.
Could anyone suggest a solution?
Note that PartialStraightPipe, PartialTwoPortFlow, PartialStraightPipe, PartialTwoPort, PartialDistributedVolume do not need to be modified.
I would like to use my own FlowModels and HeatTransfer models, but this is the next stage. - yet guidance would be helpful.
model w2DynamicPipe1 "Dynamic pipe model with storage of mass and energy"
  import Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure;
  // extending PartialStraightPipe
  extends Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.PartialStraightPipe(final port_a_exposesState = modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_b or modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_vb, final port_b_exposesState = modelStructure == ModelStructure.a_vb or modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_vb);
  // extending PartialTwoPortFlow
  extends Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.PartialTwoPortFlow (final lengths = fill(length / n, n), final crossAreas = fill(crossArea, n), final dimensions = fill(4 * crossArea / perimeter, n), final roughnesses = fill(roughness, n), final dheights = height_ab * dxs);
  // Wall heat transfer

This returns the following:
[86] 12:23 Validation of w2DynamicPipe1 finished 
Notification: Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.PartialTwoPort [3:5-3:5] Missing inner. Outer declaration system is missing a corresponding inner declaration. An inner declaration will be added using the outer declaration.
Error: Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.PartialDistributedVolume [34:5-34:5] Invalid instantiation. Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium.BaseProperties is partial.
Validation of model w2_Models.w2pipes.w2DynamicPipe1 completed with 1 error.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.
Thanks for the help.

As a first hint, Dymola reports:
Inherited "port_a_exposesState" conflict with other inherited. Should be identical. Introduced via extends PartialTwoPort  Error: Component port_a_exposesState = (modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_b) or (modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_vb), but previously port_a_exposesState = modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_b or modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_vb. The components are not identical.
after adding end w2DynamicPipe1; to the code above

The rules for multiple inheritance are fairly strict in Modelica, and as Markus A. noted the model generates errors due to that.
That can be handled by adding the corresponding parenthesis given the following:
model w2DynamicPipe1 "Dynamic pipe model with storage of mass and energy"
  import Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure;
  // extending PartialStraightPipe
  extends Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.PartialStraightPipe(final port_a_exposesState = (modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_b) or (modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_vb), final port_b_exposesState = (modelStructure == ModelStructure.a_vb) or (modelStructure == ModelStructure.av_vb));
  // extending PartialTwoPortFlow
  extends Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.PartialTwoPortFlow (final lengths = fill(length / n, n), final crossAreas = fill(crossArea, n), final dimensions = fill(4 * crossArea / perimeter, n), final roughnesses = fill(roughness, n), final dheights = height_ab * dxs);
  // Wall heat transfer
  parameter Real dxs[:];
end w2DynamicPipe1;

That model checks in Dymola, and should be usable as a starting point.
There are still notes about BaseProperties being partial and that it contains an outer system (both of them are ok for a component-model - but should be handled in the system), and I don't know what size the vector dxs should have.
